# FPDF & MySQL : Generate yearly report

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I would like to generate a yearly report where I get the data from MySQL database and display it on PDF report.

This is my current code for now:

```html
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 12);
$pdf->Cell(50,5, 'Book Publication Report','0','1','L',false);
$pdf->Ln(3);

$year = "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_year) FROM book_publication";
$exec = mysqli_query($conn, $year);

$pdf->SetFont('times','B',7);
$pdf->Cell(10,6,'No',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Staff',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(23,6,'Publication Year',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(35,6,'Book Title',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Publisher',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'ISBN Number',1,0,'C');

$query = "SELECT * FROM book_publication";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
 $pdf->Ln(6);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 7);
 $pdf->Cell(10,6,$row['no'],1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['member_name'],1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(23,6,$row['pub_year'],1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row['book_title'],1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['publisher'],1,0,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['isbn_num'],1,0,'C');
}
```

From the code I have right now, I think I have extracted the date from pub_year, but I'm not sure if I'm completely right. I think maybe I can just use one query for this but I'm not sure how.

Sorry if this is just a simple question but I have googled and read the asked questions here but I'm still confused. Can someone tell me if my query is correct or point out where I did wrong? And if possible, what the next step is? Thanks..

Comment: no idea what you are asking? if its just about the query then only show that

Comment: @Dagon no, i want to display data group by year, but i'm not sure if what i'm doing is correct

Comment: You did not fetch data from your query in `$year` variable.